# How to show convergence in law using Berry-Esseen's theorem (Poisson)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

## Setup

r.v. $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim i.i.d. Po(\lambda)$. Now I consider a testing $H_0: \lambda = \lambda_0, H_1: \lambda > \lambda_0$.

This is Example 3.3.2 of "Elements of Large-Sample Theory" (p.162).

## Question

I need to show that
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\lambda_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} \xrightarrow{L} N(0,1)\ \ \ \mathrm{as}\ \lambda_n \to \lambda_0.
\end{align}

## What I know

$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_1 - \lambda_n|^3]}{\lambda_n^{3/2}} \to \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_1 - \lambda_0|^3]}{\lambda_0^{3/2}} < \infty\ \ \ \mathrm{as}\ \lambda_n \to \lambda_0.
$$
follows from the fact that
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X_1 - \lambda_n|^3] \to \mathbb{E}[|X_1 - \lambda_0|^3] < \infty,\\ \lambda_n^{3/2} \to \lambda_0^{3/2} > 0.
$$

Therefore, from Berry-Esseen Theorem, we get
$$
|F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_1 - \lambda_n|^3]}{\lambda_n^{3/2}},
$$
where $F_n(x)$ is CDF of $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\lambda_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}$, and $C$ is constant.

**How can we transform the convergence(in law) "Qustion" from here?**

Comment: You sure it's not $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n-\lambda)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$?

Comment: @Snoop $\lambda$ is fixed alternative in sequence $\lambda_n$. Now I consider $\lambda_n$.

Comment: Yes, I meant for the sqrt of $n$, if it is.

Comment: @Snoop Sorry, your point is correct. I will rewrite it.

Comment: I think Berry-Esseen Theorem is usually for stated for i.i.d. random variables, right? But, here $\lambda_n$ is not a constant so I don't think you can apply the theorem without making any adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update in the end**

The claimed convergence does not hold in general without assuming stronger convergence on $\lambda_n \to \lambda_0$.

In fact, for $\lambda_n = \lambda_0 - c\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_0}{n}}$, we can show
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} \to N(c, 1), \text{ weakly}.
$$

Too see this, we first note that the usual CLT for i.i.d. random variables implies
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_0)}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}} \to N(0, 1), \text{ weakly}.
$$

With this in mind, let us rewrite $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}$ as
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_0 + \lambda_0 - \lambda_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_0)}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_n}} + \frac{\sqrt{n}(\lambda_0 - \lambda_n)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}
$$

The first term $\to N(0, 1)$ weakly as $n\to \infty$ since $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_0)}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}} \to N(0, 1)$ and $\lambda_n \to \lambda_0$.

The second term $ = \frac{\sqrt{n}c\sqrt{\lambda_0/n}}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} = \frac{c\sqrt{\lambda_0}}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} \to c$ as $n\to \infty$.

Combining, we conclude that (first term) + (second term) $\to N(c, 1)$ weakly.

As you can see from above, the problem here is the convergence of $\lambda_n \to \lambda_0$ is too slow. By assuming faster convergence, we can show your claim.

Alternatively, you can prove $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \lambda_0)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} \to N(0, 1)$ without assuming faster convergence of $\lambda_n$.

**Update:**

It seems like the author is assuming $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda_n)$ rather than $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$. The difference is that $\lambda_n$ changes as $n$ increases, so $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is not really a regular sequence, it is a triangular sequence ($X_i$ should be rather written as $X_{i,n}$ to explicitly show dependence on $n$.). In that case, all you have to do is to observe the right hand side of your inequality
$$
|F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_1 - \lambda_n|^3]}{\lambda_n^{3/2}},
$$
converges to zero as $n\to \infty$.